# React native image crop picker network issue .... on api hit with axios

Tags: react-native

Ios working fine
Android = network issue

I am stuck from so many days
RN version = 0.63.4
Rn crop picker version = 0.36.1

From R&D
I did all sloution like

1. upgarde flipper version
2. comment flipper line = android/app/debug/flipeerfile

Here i am attatching code of axios , image uploading file

1. axios code =

```
// import axios from "axios";
// import { SiteUrl } from '../config/Setting';

// var instance = axios.create({
//     baseURL: 'http://192.168.1.90:3000/api/v1/user-service/users/',
//     timeout: 60000,
//     headers: {
//     'Content-Type': 'application/json',
//     'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
//     'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': '*',
//     },
// });

// instance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
//     console.log('config is ',config)
//     return config;
// }, function (error) {
//     return error;
// });

// instance.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
//     // console.log('response of axios',response)
//     return response;
// }, function (error) {
//     console.log('error of axios',error)
//     return error;
// })

// export default instance;

import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';
import {SiteUrl} from '../config/Setting';

function parseError(messages) {
  // error
  // console.log('message',messages)
  if (messages) {
    if (messages instanceof Array) {
      return Promise.reject({messages: messages});
    } else {
      return Promise.reject({messages: [messages]});
    }
  } else {
    return Promise.reject({messages: ['エラーが発生しました']});
  }
}

/**
 * parse response
 */
function parseBody(response) {
  //  if (response.status === 200 && response.data.status.code === 200) { // - if use custom status code
  // if (response.status === 200) {
  return response;
  // return response.data.result
  // } else {
  //   console.log('message',response)
  //   return this.parseError(response.data)
  // }
}

/**
 * axios instance
 */

let instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://14.98.110.243:3000/api/v1/user-service/users/',
  paramsSerializer: function (params) {
    return qs.stringify(params, {indices: false});
  },
});

// request header
instance.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    console.log('config is = ', config);
    // Do something before request is sent

    let apiToken = '';
    apiToken = await AsyncStorage.getItem('apiToken');
    console.log('apiToken', apiToken);
    config.headers = {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${JSON.parse(apiToken)}`,
      'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    };
    return config;
  },
  error => {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  },
);

// response parse
instance.interceptors.response.use(
  response => {
    return parseBody(response);
  },
  error => {
    // console.warn('Error status', error.response.status)
    // return Promise.reject(error)
    if (error.response) {
      return parseError(error.response.data);
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  },
);

export default instance;
```

2. Here is file code =

i am using hooks ... and i want to store multiple image in array with path

`const [images, setImages] = useState([]);`

````
        const image = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
          height: 385,
          maxFiles: 6,
          minFiles: 3,
          mediaType: 'photo',
          multiple: true,
          width: 1000,
        }).then(image => {
          console.log('imahge', image);

          let images = [];
          images = images;

          image.forEach((ele, i) => {
            images.push(ele.path);
          });

          setImages(images);
          console.log('all', images);
        });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error:', error);
      }
    ```
````

Answer (score 0):

not an expert, but where are you calling the method to upload the image. I had these issue of "Network Error" using Fetch and solved it using a Form Data object. Here's my code:

```
ImagePicker.openPicker({
    multiple: true,
    forceJpg: true,
    maxFiles: 5,
    compressImageQuality: 0.5,
    mediaType: 'photo'
})
.then(images =>{
    //map of around the pictures and return a form data that will be passed to whole.js
    images.map((item, index) => {
        this.setState({numberImages: this.state.numberImages + 1})
        this.state.formData.append("photo", {
            uri: item.path,
            type: "image/jpeg",
            name: `pickedImage-${index}.jpg`
        })
        
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

finally i got an answer actually my backend team use a package that want mime type also in image object ...
so when i send that it working fine ...

for eg =>
`` this.state.formData.append("photo", { uri: item.path, mime:"image/jpeg", type: "image/jpeg", name: `pickedImage-${index}.jpg` }) ``